# how to add bootstrap modal to update action in YII2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I know the below code creates bootstrap modal with ADD button. I want to make this work in update button. And below that is the yii2 action column of index page. 
I need to open bootstrap modal when the update button is clicked.

**Modal Code**

```
            Modal::begin([
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success'
            ],
                'closeButton' => [
                'label' => 'Close',
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right',
            ],
                'size' => 'modal-lg',
            ]);
                $newmodel = new Comment();

                echo $this->render('/comment/create', ['model' => $newmodel]);

            Modal::end();
```

**Action Column in index page**

```
  [
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{update} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{delete}',
    /* 'buttons'=>[
        'view' => function ($url, $comment) {     
           return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                     </span>',$url,           
            [
                'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'view'),
             ]);
         }
        ], */
      'urlCreator' => function ($action, $dataProvider, $key, $index) {
        if ($action === 'view') {
            $url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('option?id='.$key.''); 
            return $url;
        }
        if ($action === 'update') {
        $url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('question/update?id='.$key.''); 
            return $url;
        }
        if ($action === 'delete') {
        $url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('question/delete?id='.$key.''); 
            return $url;
         }
      }
 ],
```

Comment: So did you make any tests, any tries or are you asking us to create the code directly for you?

Comment: I tried it by placing the code in button section accordingly. But, it shown many errors. So I'm asking for any easy implementation. I need to render update form when the update button is clicked.

Comment: Look http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/